# How to show div in middle of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, absolute

I design a page with many small image and i like when small images clicked then open a fixed div and show my large image, it's work perfect for image that in up of page but when scroll drop down to bottom of page it's now work well, what is truble

```
function LoadShowDiv () {
    $('.BackgroudShade').slideDown(800);   // shade of background will be visible
    $(".DivOfImage").show();               // Div of Large Image will be visible          
// When Image loaded successful then set width,height and top,left of Large Image Div 
// but i want set top,left when screen is scroll down to bottom of page
// then show Div at middle of screen in every time
    $('.LargeImage').load(function() {     
       $('.DivOfImage').width($('.LargeImage').width());
       $('.DivOfImage').height($('.LargeImage').height());
       var LeftPostion = (WidthOfScreen - $('.LargeImage').width()) / 2;
       var TopPostion = (HeightOfScreen - $('.LargeImage').height()) / 2;
       $(".DivOfImage").offset({ top: TopPostion, left: LeftPostion});
       $('.LargeImage').show(1000);
    })
}

$('#SmallImage').click(function(){
    $('.LargeImage').attr('src','LargeImage.jpg');
    LoadShowDiv();
})

.DivOfImage {
    border: 8px solid #FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<!-- This is Div of small Image -->
<div class="Image_DIV" id="Image20">
  <table>
   <tr><td class="Image"><img src="Chosen/Small/20.jpg"/></td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="ImageDescribe"></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- This is Div of Large Image and Background Shade -->
<div class="BackgroudShade"></div>
<div class="DivOfImage"><img class="LargeImage"/></div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML as well pls?

Comment: <!-- This is Div of small Image -->
<div class="Image_DIV" id="Image20">
  <table>
   <tr><td class="Image"><img src="Chosen/Small/20.jpg"/></td></tr>
   <tr>
     <td class="ImageDescribe"></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- This is Div of Large Image and Background Shade -->
<div class="BackgroudShade"></div>
<div class="DivOfImage"><img class="LargeImage"/></div>

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:fixed;` from your `css` use only `position:absolute;` like,

```
.DivOfImage {
    border: 8px solid #FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:absolute;// use absolute only
}
```

Using `Fixed` after `Absolute` overwrites your `position property` and will not make it `absolute`

Comment: I Remove it but when screen is scroll down it's not work, this mean is when click on small image position of Large Image is always on top of screen and i don't like it, i want this always appear in center of screen